# Sonarqube 6.5 coverage exclusions are applying globally

Tags: sonarqube

I am using SonarQube 6.5 version where currently i am facing issue in adding coverage exclusions where if I add at project level (Projects->Administration->General Settings->Analysis Scope->Code Coverage) after that if I open any project's(Projects->Administration->General Settings->Analysis Scope->Code Coverage) all exclusions of previous project's appearing. or If I open global settings (Administration->General Settings->Analysis Scope->Code Coverage) i see all project's exclusions files instead of at a specific project's scope. is it a bug?

Coverage Exclusions
Key: sonar.coverage.exclusions

Comment: Please explain more what you want to do and what you have researched. your question has nothing to do with programming, it is of type very low quality

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your navigation path to where you're editing these values.

Comment: thanks for quick response. I tried to elaborate as much as I can.

Comment: G. Ann could you help me out here. why project level exclusions are showing up in global exclusions and in all other projects.